# How to capture requests to localhost using Intellij and Fiddler?

Tags: intellij-idea, fiddler

Trying to set up IntelliJ and Fiddler to capture requests to localhost.

I want to see the exact request + network details coming from an end to end test running in IntelliJ, and downloaded Fiddler + followed the steps for allowing Fiddler to capture traffic from IntelliJ here: https://medium.com/@siddhartha.khare/how-to-capture-intellij-traffic-through-fiddler-8c69d1f6d080

Issue is that this is not working, possibly because the endpoint I'm trying to hit is my own locally running application on http://localhost:8080/... is there a way to get Fiddler working here?